# Cant figure out the use of RNDateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetimepicker

I'm trying to create a mobile application which consists of a field to get date of birth. Unfortunately [DateTimePicker module](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker#react-native-datetimepicker) wasn't give me an output. As it says  is old I have used

```
<RNDateTimePicker mode="date" value={new Date()} />
```

in my implementation. 
It shows the date time picker but I cant get its output in to the text field. I would highly appriciate if you can provide me with an example on how to use RNDateTimePicker. Following is the code i'm working with.

```
    import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import RNDateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

export default class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.reg_form}>
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="Name you want us to call you" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} />
                {/* Field to put DOB */}
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="Date of birth" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} />
                {/* RNDateTimePicker */}
                <RNDateTimePicker mode="date" value={new Date()} />
                {/* need to populate the output of this datetimepicker in DOB inputText */}
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="email address" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} autoCompleteType="email" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    reg_form: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        paddingLeft: 50,
        paddingRight: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        paddingTop: 100,
    },
    textinput: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        height: 40,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderColor: "#5d5959",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        color: "#5d5959"
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `date` value in your `state` so that you can update it with an event handler and pass it to the `RNDateTimePicker` component.

Then in the `setDate()` function, you handle the event and update `this.state.date` with the selected value.

For example:

```
export default class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
       date: new Date()
    }

    setDate = (event, date) => {
       date = date || this.state.date;

       this.setState({
          date
       });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.reg_form}>
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="Name you want us to call you" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} />
                {/* Field to put DOB */}
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="Date of birth" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} value={this.state.date} />
                {/* RNDateTimePicker */}
                <RNDateTimePicker mode="date" value={this.state.date} onChange={this.setDate} />
                {/* need to populate the output of this datetimepicker in DOB inputText */}
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="email address" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} autoCompleteType="email" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This part I can understand. The part I don't understand is how I can populate  "TextInput - Date of Birth" with the selected value. Can you explain that to me.

Comment: @Sandaru Then you should bind your new variable `this.state.date` with the `value` props of the `TextInput` component. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi , I am not able to use it like a component . but working fine as a new container (like navigate to that container ) .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import moment
then youll need a var for the initial value

and a little function for the value change

Hope this works 4 u

```
import moment from 'moment';   

 export default class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      initialValue: new Date(2000, 10, 11),
    };
  }
    render() {
       const {
         initialValue,
            } = this.state;
      const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
         const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
         setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
         setDate(currentDate);
         };
        return (
            <View style={styles.reg_form}>
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="Name you want us to call you" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} />
                {/* Field to put DOB */}
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="Date of birth" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} />
                {/* RNDateTimePicker */}
                mode="date"
              textColor="orange"
              value={initialValue}
              display="default"
              style={{width: width / 6, height: 40}}
              onChange={(event, value) => {
                this.setState({
                  initialValue: value,
                });
                //console.log(moment(value).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
              }}
                {/* need to populate the output of this datetimepicker in DOB inputText */}
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder="email address" underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} autoCompleteType="email" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```